# Presenting ticks for every plotted points

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am new to Python and programming in general.

I am attempting to plot value for every week on a bar chart. I would like to have ticks on the x axis under every plotted point so it is easy to understand the relation between values and dates.

I have a Pandas `dataframe(df_clean)` that looks like this (sorry for the french column name):

```
Data columns (total 20 columns):
Statut                    23467 non-null object
P.O                       23467 non-null object
Fournisseur               23467 non-null object
Date Comm.                23467 non-null object
Date Annul.               23466 non-null object
Date TPA                  23467 non-null object
Qté Comm.                 23467 non-null float64
Courant comm.             23467 non-null float64
Cout comm.                23467 non-null float64
Qté recue                 23467 non-null float64
Courant recue             23467 non-null float64
Cout recue                23467 non-null float64
Qté souff.                23467 non-null float64
Courant souff.            23467 non-null float64
Cout souff.               23467 non-null float64
% recue                   23467 non-null float64
% MB                      23467 non-null float64
Premier jour sem. TPA     23467 non-null object
Year TPA                  23467 non-null int64
Jour de la semaine TPA    23467 non-null object
```

My goal is to plot the sum of `df_clean["Cout comm."]` for every `df_clean["Premier jour sem. TPA"]`. I would like it to look like this:

[image: Desired result]

Here is the code up to now

```
#Group by first day of week
sem_tpa_group = df_clean.groupby("Premier jour sem. TPA").agg("sum")
sem_tpa_group.reset_index(inplace=True)

#Limit the amount of week to show
sem_tpa_group = sem_tpa_group[sem_tpa_group["Premier jour sem. TPA"] > date.today()]

#Create graph
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(sem_tpa_group["Premier jour sem. TPA"], sem_tpa_group["Cout comm."],'o-',label='Ord. cost')
plt.plot(sem_tpa_group["Premier jour sem. TPA"], sem_tpa_group["Cout recue"],'o-',label='Rec. cost')
plt.legend(loc=1)
plt.ylabel('Cost')
plt.xlabel('Week date')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The result is this:

[image: Result]

Would anyone be able to tell me how to get tick information for every plotted point on the x axis?

I tried `plt.xticks()` without any result though I am not sure I did use it the right way.

Thanks a lot for everything

Comment: Something like `plt.xticks(matplotlib.dates.date2num((sem_tpa_group["Premier jour sem. TPA"])))` may work.  Hard to tell what units that is in though.  In general matplotlib represents dates as flaoting point days since 0000-01-01

Comment: The "desired" plot is very likely produced by `df.plot.bar`. Pandas bar plots are categorical. Matplotlib `bar` plots, as well as line `plot`s, are numeric plots. You may still achieve categorical plots with matplotlib by converting your datetime index/column to strings before plotting.